# Making an api with Express.js and Nuxt.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, api, express, nuxt.js

I am currently working on a website where i store data inside Firebase and i would like to write and read data from Firebase thru an api. I am trying to build my own api with Express.js and Nuxt.js.

Inside the root of my project i made a new folder named 'api', inside that folder i have a routes folder where all my routes go. Then i two more files inside the api folder named 'index.js' and 'dev-server.js'.
This is the folder structure:

```
/api
  /routes
    user.js
dev-server.js
index.js
```

this is the inside of the `dev-server.js`:

```
const debug = require('debug')('Shutterminds:api');

import express from 'express';

import api from '@/api';

const app = express();

app.use((req, res, next) => {
  debug(`[${req.method}] ${req.url}`);

  next();
});

app.use(api.path, api.handler);

const port = Number(3000);

app.listen(port, () => debug(`Listing on http://localhost:3000`));
```

This is the inside of the `index.js`:

```
import path from 'path';
import glob from 'glob';
import express from 'express';

// Create express instance
const app = express();

glob
  .sync(`${__dirname}/routes/*.js`)
  .forEach(file =>
  {
    const route = require(file);
    app.use(`/${path.basename(file, '.js')}`, route.default);
  });

// Export the server middleware
module.exports = {
  path: '/api',
  handler: app
};
```

Then in my `nuxt.config.js` i set the serverMiddleware to:

`serverMiddleware: '@/api',`

Then i set a proxy to:

`proxy: { '/api': 'http://localhost:3000' },`

After i run yarn dev i expect the express server to start, but it doesnt. Whenever i run the command it keeps getting stuck at the line `[nodemon] clean exit - waiting for changes before restart`.
this is the full log:

```
$ cross-env NODE_ENV=development nodemon server/index.js --watch server
[nodemon] 1.19.4
[nodemon] to restart at any time, enter `rs`
[nodemon] watching dir(s): server\**\*
[nodemon] watching extensions: js,mjs,json
[nodemon] starting `node server/index.js`
[nodemon] clean exit - waiting for changes before restart
```

Can someone please tell me what im doing wrong? This is the first time i am trying to make an api so im still a beginner at this. I would really appreciate some Feedback!

Comment: may help https://www.reddit.com/r/Nuxt/comments/ffvzxr/simple_crud_app_using_express_nuxtjs_using/

Comment: @PirateApp Thank you! I will definitely look into this article! Bylooking over it for about a minute it looks like this is exactly what i need!